# MVC subController

Tags: model-view-controller

My application has the following module:

/groups/{id_group} -- > GroupController.php

My question is this,

/groups/{id_group}/events/{id_event}

Which controller should handle this?

Comment: why is this tagged with asp.net-mvc and what PHP framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using groups/n/ as routing, you would want to use your framework's routing system to route to the event controller. Otherwise, it is the groups controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to just using the first parameter as the Controller, then consider using the further parameters as purely parts of the query string e.g

```
?controller=groups&itemId={id_group}&action=events&actionId={id_event)
```

and use the controller to route it to the correct place e.g.

```
$model->getGroup($id_group, 'events', $id_event);
```